# CodeIgniter, Smarty and Form Helper. Wrong Link on Submit

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

i have al litte problem with using CodeIgniter Form Helper and Smarty.

I used this (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Form-helper-with-Smarty) Form Helper Function.

Now i have the addUser() Function in Controller

```
    public function addUser(){
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Benutzername', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Passwort', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Passwort bestätigen', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            echo "Error! User can not create";
        }else{
            $this->user_model->add_user();
            echo "Done!";
        }
        $this->smarty->display($this->tpl);
    }
```

And the following .TPL i used

```
    {form url='pageadmin/addUser'}
<p>
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="user_name" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="email_address">Your Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email_address" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="con_password">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="con_password" name="con_password" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
{form}
```

But now, when i try this. I have two problems. The first is, that the message "Error! User can not create" is all time showed when i called the function addUser(). The second problem is, that the url, which is generating by the form submit, is like this "http://dev.url.de/admin/addUser/dev.url.de/pageadmin/addUser".

thank you very much and sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your form is failing but you're not returning WHY it's failing. Change your code as below, this will tell you where to look to find out what isn't passing validation:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            echo validation_errors();
        }else{
```

The validation errors will tell you which rule(s) is/are the problem, then you can continue to troubleshoot from there.

As to the URL it's simply because of relative URL's, I don't use Smarty so not sure how to use base_url() but the following "might" work

```
{form url=base_url().'pageadmin/addUser'}
```

If that doesn't work this should:

```
{form url='../pageadmin/addUser'}
```

Comment: The first issue is now fixed,but the second problem is still there.
I tried both solutions from you. The URL was the same in both cases.

Comment: perhaps this will help with the URL issue: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Use-URL-helper-from-Smarty

Comment: I change it to {form url=$base_url|cat:'admin/addUser'}

$base_url is the base_url() function from codeigniter.

And now i have http://dev.url.de/admin/addUser/dev.url.de/dev.url.de/admin/addUser

Comment: Okay. I find the fault. In config file i write $config['base_url'] = 'dev.url.de'; instat of $config['base_url'] = 'http://dev.url.de/';